# Remove object from nested array if array is empty in Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

How can I remove the object if the nested array is empty. Like I have an **array:**

```
pokemonGroups = [
    {
      name: 'Grass',
      pokemon: [
        'bulbasaur-0', 'Bulbasaur', 'oddish-1','Oddish','bellsprout-2', 'Bellsprout'
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Water',
      pokemon: [

      ]
    }]
```

So In this we have an empty array

```
{
   name: 'Water',
   pokemon: []
}
```

So I want to remove this object and my array should be like:

```
pokemonGroups = [
    {
      name: 'Grass',
      pokemon: [
        'bulbasaur-0', 'Bulbasaur', 'oddish-1','Oddish','bellsprout-2', 'Bellsprout'
      ]
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter:

```
pokemonGroups = pokemonGroups.filter(group => group.pokemon.length != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate your array and use array.splice()

```js
var pokemonGroups = [{
    name: 'Grass',
    pokemon: [
      'bulbasaur-0', 'Bulbasaur', 'oddish-1', 'Oddish', 'bellsprout-2', 'Bellsprout'
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Water',
    pokemon: [

    ]
  }
]

for (var i = 0; i < pokemonGroups.length; i++) {
  if (pokemonGroups[i]['pokemon'].length == 0) {
    pokemonGroups.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

console.log(pokemonGroups)
```